# Upload file to remote server using ajax

Tags: ajax

I don't have any control on the server side..
is it possible to upload and load the results given by the remote server in an Iframe ?
please share some code..
Thanks

Comment: You mean this? <iframe src ="***share.com/upload.php" width="50%" height="500"></iframe>

Comment: hi Matias,
I want to put normal form, but load results in an Iframe..

thanks :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare the iframe with a name and target that name in your form element:

```
<form action="http://url.to.server" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="resultsFrame">
    <input type="file" />
    ...
</form>

<iframe src="blank.html" name="resultsFrame"></iframe>
```